# MySQL: how many space does text occupy?

Tags: mysql, memory, text

I read on the Net that a text record is equivalent to 64kb. My question is: if I insert just one character into a record, will it occupies all the 64kb or less? I ask this because I think I won't need all the 64kb but probably less.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Forgive me... I will just paste documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: No, one character would take only a few bytes. the formula is : L + 2 bytes when L is the length of the text. So a standard page of a paperback book would occupy about 2KB of storage.

Comment: What happens is that your string/text gets written and additional 2 bytes are glued at the end. Those 2 bytes contain the length of the text you've written down and the max. number you can store in 2 bytes is 2 ^ 16 = 65536, which is where 64KB limit comes from. That's the optimization, so no, it's not entire 64kb that get allocated, it's length(text) + 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT

- For TINYTEXT: (Actual length in bytes of a given string value) + (1
  Byte)
- **For TEXT: (Actual length in bytes of a given string value) + (2
  Bytes)**
- For MEDIUMTEXT: (Actual length in bytes of a given string
  value) + (3 Bytes)
- For LONGTEXT: (Actual length in bytes of a given
  string value) + (4 Bytes)

*Trailing spaces are not considered for storage or retrieval.*

More info: [Storage Requirements for String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) (GarciaPL just mentioned it :))

Hope it helps!